# copying an integer

Tags: c#

This makes me fee like a knucklehead but how do I say

```
previousError = currentError;
```

I mean that doesn't work of course, If I change current error then previous error is changed - there has to be an easy way to do this... I have an extension method that creates a deep clone of objects that I use at work all of the time but I would think for integers it should be easier than serializing and deserializing them?

Ahh... Thanks

Comment: You are going to need to provide a little more information. Why doesn't this work for you? What are you trying to achieve? If you use the above statement (and assuming they are integers), then previousError does NOT change when you change currentError.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are incorrect.

Integers are immutable value types; changing `currentError` will not affect `previousError`
.

Comment: Right - this is beginning to make me question my sanity... There has to be a logic error somewhere that is causing this but it's a pretty simple program.